# How can I get changed attributes on update using JPA/EclipseLink

Tags: java, jpa, jpa-2.0, eclipselink

How can I get changed attributes (name, old value, new value) on update using JPA/EclipseLink?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the changes from the UnitOfWork or through DescriptorEvents.  You can get the new value from the change set, and as of 2.3 I think, you can also get the old value.

See,

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/FAQ/JPA#How_to_access_what_changed_in_an_object_or_transaction.3F